# にする and indirect speech

Tags: grammar, particle-に

I came across this sentence during my immersion:
YOUさんに婿にしたいランキングぶっちぎりのビリという
I don't get the meaning of にしたい in this case.
Moreover, shouldn't it be YOUさんは since she's the agent of the quotation?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130024/discussion-on-question-by-andrea22--and-indirect-speech).

Comment: Thanks for the translation, but why would you translate にしたい with “want to have”?

Answer (score 1):

In the video, I think Yama-chan says:

> 「YOUさんに、『婿にしたいランキングぶっちぎりのビリ』と**言われ**た (or 言われて)...」

YOUさんに...言われた means "I was told by YOU-san" (i.e. "YOU-san told me").

婿にしたい literally means "want to make (someone) one's 婿".

[婿]{むこ} can mean either "husband / groom" or "son-in-law / daughter's husband or fiancé".

From the surrounding context in the video, Yama-chan got lost in a supermarket in Hawaii and YOU-san told him 「(山ちゃんは)婿にしたいランキングぶっちぎりのビリ(だ)」, "You're in the lowest position of the ranking list of people I would want to make my 婿 / want to choose as my 婿," because Yama-chan is too 頼りない(unreliable), compared to Tokui-san.